Propagate reactive Mono context to Caffeine AsyncCache
In our reactive application (Spring WebFlux, project Reactor) we carry important logging information within the reactive context. The problem is when we use the Caffeine AsyncCache, the context is not automatically transferred between the calling Mono and the caffeine cache Future.
I'd like to share our solution as I think some others might have the same need.

The solution is in the code, with added comments
This is the main testing class:
import com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.AsyncCache;
import com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import java.util.Map;

class ContextFromMonoToCaffeineCache {

    @Test
    void context() {
        final UserService userService = new UserService();

        // Call the user service 4 times, each time with a different context.

        // Fetch the user with ID=1 twice, using the method which loses the context.
        // The 1st fetch is from the database, the 2nd is already from the cache.
        userService.getUserWithoutContext(1)
                .delayUntil(this::printUser)
                .contextWrite(context -> context.put("myContext", "FIRST"))
                .block();
        userService.getUserWithoutContext(1)
                .delayUntil(this::printUser)
                .contextWrite(context -> context.put("myContext", "SECOND"))
                .block();
        // Fetch the user with ID=2 twice, using the context preserving fetch.
        // The 1st fetch is from the database, the 2nd is already from the cache.
        userService.getUserWithContext(2)
                .delayUntil(this::printUser)
                .contextWrite(context -> context.put("myContext", "THIRD"))
                .block();
        userService.getUserWithContext(2)
                .delayUntil(this::printUser)
                .contextWrite(context -> context.put("myContext", "FORTH"))
                .block();
    }

    private Mono<Object> printUser(User user) {
        return Mono.deferContextual(context -> {
            System.out.printf("Found %s, with myContext: %s %n", user, context.get("myContext"));
            return Mono.empty();
        });
    }
}


The output is:
Fetched for ID: 1, with myContext: N/A 
Found User[id=1, name=Alex], with myContext: FIRST 
Found User[id=1, name=Alex], with myContext: SECOND 
Fetched for ID: 2, with myContext: THIRD 
Found User[id=2, name=Betty], with myContext: THIRD 
Found User[id=2, name=Betty], with myContext: FORTH 

As you can see, the cache works as expected. Each ID is fetched from the "database" only once.
ID=1 was fetched without the context handling,
ID=2 has the context properly handled.
The UserService class uses Caffeine AsyncCache.
cache.get() has 2 parameters:

The key to search for.
A lambda telling how to fetch the data if they are not yet in the cache.

class UserService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository = new UserRepository();
    private final AsyncCache<Integer, User> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder().buildAsync();

    public Mono<User> getUserWithoutContext(Integer userKey) {
        return Mono.deferContextual(contextView -> Mono.fromCompletionStage(cache.get(userKey,
                // Executed when the key is not in the cache yet:
                (key, executor) -> userRepository.fetchUser(key)
                        .toFuture()
        )));
    }

    public Mono<User> getUserWithContext(Integer userKey) {
        return Mono.deferContextual(contextView -> Mono.fromCompletionStage(cache.get(userKey,
                // Executed when the key is not in the cache yet:
                (key, executor) -> userRepository.fetchUser(key)
                        // Copy the context.
                        // Notice that the call of contextWrite() must be AFTER the call of fetchUser(),
                        // as it is propagated upstream and not downstream.
                        .contextWrite(context -> context.put("myContext", contextView.get("myContext")))
                        .toFuture()
        )));
    }
}

UserRepository is just a simulated database repository.
In the fetchUser() method we inspect the context and print it out to demonstrate if it has or has not been properly propagated.
class UserRepository {
    // Simulated database table
    final private Map<Integer, User> users = Map.of(
            1, new User(1, "Alex"),
            2, new User(2, "Betty")
    );

    public Mono<User> fetchUser(Integer userKey) {
        return Mono.just(userKey)
                // Let's check what is in the context
                .transformDeferredContextual((integerMono, contextView) -> {
                    System.out.printf("Fetched for ID: %s, with myContext: %s %n", 
                            userKey, contextView.getOrDefault("myContext", "N/A"));
                    return integerMono;
                })
                // Simulate the database fetch
                .mapNotNull(users::get);
    }
}

User is our business object:
record User(Integer id, String name) {}

